# django_cron not sending email

Tags: python, django, email, cron

I have just installed `django_cron` not `django_crontab` though, somehow I am trying to send an email as notification but it just wouldn't work.

this is just for testing purpose so I set it to 1 minute.
the code was a bit more complex before but it didn't work so I used the most simplified way to send email in order to make sure that it's not working.  Also even used it as a `post` method to test, and it tested out working perfectly if a post method called the follow codes

```
class MyCronJob(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 1  # every minute

    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'Email_Test'    # a unique code

    def do(self):
        print('######################################')
        send_mail(
            'Subject here from cron',
            'Here is the message.',
            'from@email.com',
            ['to@emailcom'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
```

I tried running `python manage.py runcrons` and `python manage.py runcrons --force` and waited, (no errors, I also added the `print` because I want to see if the code even runs and good, I see the `#################` got printed)

can someone please give me an advise?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try a custom function for sending mail. I tried `send_mail` function and it did not work for me and i did not find any bug or explanation on this topic. Below is an example of sending html emails using [smtplib.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html)

```
import smtplib
def send_email(email, subject, message):
    text = subject
    html = message
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    html_part = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    text_part = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    msg.attach(text_part)
    msg.attach(html_part)
    msg['Subject'] =  subject
    msg['From'] = SENDER_EMAIL
    msg['To'] = email
    s = smtplib.SMTP(settings.GMAIL_SMTP)
    s.ehlo()
    s.starttls()
    s.login(SENDER_EMAIL, SENDER_PASSWORD)
    s.sendmail(SENDER_EMAIL, email, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

please make sure first you must have to import library from django.core.mail, to using send_mail. I know it's too late to help, but u can try this..

```
from django_cron import CronJobBase, Schedule
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class my_scheduled_job(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 1
    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'user_dashboard.autoemail.my_scheduled_job'

    def do(self):
        subject= 'Send Email With Automatic Schedule'
        message= 'Test send email :'
        email_to= ['xxxxxxxx@gmail.com']
        email_user(subject_test, message_test, email_to_test)
        print ("done")

    def email_user(subject, message, email_to):
        email_from = 'noreply@xxxx.id'
        send = send_mail(subject, message, email_from, email_to)
        return send
```